# How to pick the child attribute from Parent Entity using Root element in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, hibernate-criteria

I am working on the Master entity which is having several child entities.My requirement in to pick the child element using the root element in Master entity.
Let me post the entity structure

```
public class MasterEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private BigInteger masterId;

private String masterNumber;


private Integer masterName;

private boolean MasterFlag;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "as_slave1_account_id")
private MappingFirst mappingFirst;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "as_slave2_account_id")
private MappingSecond mappingSecond;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "as_slave3_account_id")
private MappingThird mappingThird;




@PrePersist
private void prePersist() {
    if (this.createdOn == null) this.createdOn = OffsetDateTime.now();
}

@PreUpdate
private void preUpdate() {
    this.lastModifiedOn = OffsetDateTime.now();
}


}
```

The first child entity

```
public class MappingFirst  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long mappingFirstId;

@NotNull(message = "account_number can't be null")
private String accountNumber;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn( name = "as_drill_down_id", referencedColumnName = "asDrillDownId")
@NotNull
private DrilDownOne drilDownOne;
    
}
```

The second child entity

```
public class DrilDownOne{

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long asDillDownId;

}
```

I am posting the class where i am trying to pull the element from the Root

```
public class MasterElementSearchCriteria implements Consumer<SearchCriteria> {
private Predicate predicate;
private CriteriaBuilder builder;
private Root rootElement;

@Override
public void accept(SearchCriteria param) {

    if (param.getValue() != null && param.getValue() != "") {
        if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(CriteriaOperationEnum.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO.getOperation())) {
            if (rootElement.get(param.getKey()).getJavaType() == LocalDate.class) {
                predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(rootElement.get(param.getKey()).as(LocalDate.class), (LocalDate) param.getValue()));
            } else {
                predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(rootElement.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue().toString()));
            }
        } else if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(CriteriaOperationEnum.LESSER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO.getOperation())) {
            if (rootElement.get(param.getKey()).getJavaType() == LocalDate.class) {
                predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(rootElement.get(param.getKey()).as(LocalDate.class), (LocalDate) param.getValue()));
            } else {
                predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(rootElement.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue().toString())); // Here i am pulling the element from the root , but here i want to pull the asDillDownId of the  DrilDownOne Entity
            }
        } else if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(CriteriaOperationEnum.EQUALS_IGNORE_CASE.getOperation())) {
            if (rootElement.get(param.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.like(builder.upper(rootElement.get(param.getKey())), CriteriaOperationEnum.LIKE.getOperation() + param.getValue().toString().toUpperCase() + CriteriaOperationEnum.LIKE.getOperation()));
            } else {
                predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.equal(rootElement.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue()));
            }
        } else if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(CriteriaOperationEnum.LIKE.getOperation())) {
            predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.like(builder.upper(rootElement.get(param.getKey())), CriteriaOperationEnum.LIKE.getOperation() + param.getValue().toString().toUpperCase() + CriteriaOperationEnum.LIKE.getOperation()));
        }
    }
}

public Predicate getPredicate() {
    return predicate;
}
}
```

My requirement is,  i want to pull the  DrilDownOne entity information using Root element. Is there a way to do that  Please suggest.

Comment: Can anyone please help

Comment: @Predrag Maric can you help ?

Comment: @Alan Hay can you help ?